# Find the dimension of $W_{A}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A\in\operatorname{M}_{10}(\mathbb C)$.  Let $W_{A}$ be the subspace of $\operatorname{M}_{10}(\mathbb C)$ spanned by $\{ A^n \mid n\geq 10 \}$ . What about the dimension of $W_{A}$?

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. I've applied an edit to your question to change the formatting. This site uses MathJaX to format maths. [Here is a link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to a quick tutorial on the use of MathJaX. Also I silently assumed that you ment C$=\mathbb C$ the space of comples numbers. If this was not you intention please say so, or you can edit the question yourself :).

Comment: For $A=0$ the space is zero. This is true for any nilpotent $A$.

Comment: I want to know what is the dimension of WA? Is it less than 10 or equal to 10 or any other? Here A is any matrix of order 10.

Comment: Have you heard about the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of a matrix?

Comment: Yes. What do u talk about? @ Arthur

Answer (score 1):

In general, the dimension of $W_A$ is at most $10$.  We may deduce the precise dimension of the basis if we know the [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) $m_A(x)$ of $A$.

We also know that $\dim(W_A) \leq \deg(m_A(x))$.  More precise bounds depend on the multiplicity of the $0$ root (i.e. on the rank of $A$).